# Transposing formula, possibly polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I'm working on a game which I would like to follow behaviour of an already existing game. Unfortunately they have an odd way of calculating a players the xp(x) requirement for a level(y).

When y is 1 to 99, with x then rounded to the nearest hundred
$$
x = 25.5y^{1.82}
$$

When y is 100 or more
$$
x = 25y^{2} + 23575y - 1023150
$$

The above formula was worked out using Excel with a Polynomial line which matched perfectly ($R^{2}=1$).  The actual rule for working it out was: `XP of previous level + XP increase required to attain previous level + 50`

Example for level 100

```
Level 98 = 1527300
Level 99 = 1555800
- Due to different formula being used for level 100+
Level 100 = 1555800 + (1555800 - 1527300) + 50
Level 100 = 1584350
```

---

What I'm struggling with is finding the reverse (y = ...) for levels(y) of 100+ that use the alternative formula.

Comment: Is it solving the quadratic in $y$ which makes problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quadratic equation has two solutions, where one solution is negative and can be dropped. The other solution is
\begin{align*}
y=\frac{1}{10} \left(\sqrt{4 x+26323825}-4715\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect. After being out of eduction for 15 years I just couldn't wrap my brain around it anymore.  Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: You are always very welcome :)